# null pointer exception

Tags: java

```
package javajazzup;

public class LoginBean{
 String loginid;
 String pwd;

 public LoginBean(){}

 public String getLoginid(){
  return loginid;
 }
 public void setLoginid(String loginid){
  this.loginid = loginid;
 }
 public String getPwd(){
  return pwd;
 }
 public void setPwd(String pwd){
  this.pwd = pwd;
 }
 public String CheckValidUser(){
  if(loginid.equals("JavaJazzUp") && pwd.equals("mypwd")){
   return "success";
  }
  else{
   return "fail";
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: either `loginid` or `pwd` is null.  That is all we can tell from the title and the code given.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, put more effort to your question so it is clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 6):

You should change your method CheckValidUser() to:

```
    public String CheckValidUser(){
      if("JavaJazzUp".equals(loginid) && "mypwd".equals(pwd)){
         return "success";
      }else{
         return "fail";
      }
    }
```

Comment: And so what, his program will not work correctly again because he hasn't set his login and password... It will return "fail" everytime...

Comment: I think he sets his login and password somewhere outside the class ( like Andreas_D has shown in his test case ) and calls the CheckValidUserMethod() for verification. Anyway, at least this function will not throw NullPointerException.

Comment: @Petar Minchev - What makes you think the login and password are not set? I see no indication of how this bean is being used.

Comment: @tylermac There is also no indication that the login and password are set:) I just thought that the bean is not properly bound to the form. There was a JSF tag before, which obviously someone removed. Anyway, I am not a fortuneteller so I can be wrong of course.

Answer (score 3):

**Testcase**

```
public static void LoginBeanTest() {
  LoginBean bean = new LoginBean();
  bean.setLoginid("JavaJazzUp");
  bean.setPwd("mypwd");
  System.out.println(bean.CheckValidUser());
  bean.setPwd("wrongpwd");
  System.out.println(bean.CheckValidUser());

  bean.setLoginid(null);
  try {
    System.out.println(bean.CheckValidUser());
  catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    System.out.println("NPE as expected");
  }

  bean.setLoginid("");
  bean.setPwd(null);
  try {
    System.out.println(bean.CheckValidUser());
  catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    System.out.println("NPE as expected");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a `null pointer` either `loginid` is `null` or `pwd` is `null`. It seems they are not set properly. But without providing more information we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your private member variables `loginid` and `pwd` are both initialized to null in your default constructor, since you don't do anything to set them to any default value.  If you dereference either one without setting them to a non-null reference you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Try it like this:

```
package javajazzup; 

public class LoginBean{ 
 String loginid; 
 String pwd; 

 public LoginBean(String user, String password)
 {
    this.loginid = user;
    this.pwd = password;
 }

 public LoginBean()
 {
    this("", "");
 } 

 public String getLoginid(){ 
  return loginid; 
 } 

 public void setLoginid(String loginid){ 
  this.loginid = loginid; 
 } 

 public String getPwd()
 { 
    return pwd; 
 } 

 public void setPwd(String pwd)
 { 
    this.pwd = pwd; 
 } 

 public boolean checkValidUser(String username, String password)
 { 
     return (loginid.equals(username) && pwd.equals(password)); 
 }
```

}